# Number of ways can the 8 people occupy the seats if no two sit in the same pair of seats

Tags: combinatorics

> A bus has 30 seats arranged in 15 pairs of seats.In how many ways can the 8 people occupy the seats if no two sit in the same pair?

My Solution:
$\binom{15}{8}$*${2}^{8}$
Choose 8 pairs of seats from 15. In each pair, the person can be seated in 2 possible ways.
Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, seems correct, assuming the 8 people are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the people are interchangable (i.e. if you take two people and just change one for the other), you are correct.

Otherwise, you would have to multiply the solution by $8!$, and you get $66,421,555,200$ total ways (10 times more than the population of earth).

Comment: What is the $8!$ multiplication for?
Is it like permutations of 8 people once we chose 8 people?

Comment: @roang Well, your solution is the number of ways you can select $8$ **seats**. But "person 1 on seat 1, person 2 on seat 2" may not be the same as "person 2 on seat 1, person 1 on seat 2". Once you select your seats, there are $8!$ ways of sitting the people down on them.

Comment: Ok. Understood now.